# Inheriting Route attribute messes up already existing actions in Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, routeattribute

I am trying to inherit `Route` attributes from a base Controller exactly according to [this](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/releases/whats-new-in-aspnet-web-api-22#ARI). Though it seems to work correctly, but it messes up the previously working actions.

Below are a minimal example of my base and child controllers.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/{controller}")]
public class MyController<TEntity, TDto>: ApiController{
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<TDto> All(){
        ...
    }

    [HttpGet, Route("lookup")]
    public virtual IEnumerable<TDto> LookupData(){
        ...
    }
}

[RoutePrefix("api/entity")]
public class EntityController : MyController<Entity, DTO>
{        
}
```

After implementing the route attribute inheritance, the `api/entity/lookup` action works but in case of `api/entity` (for `All`), `ActionSelector` returns 2 actions, both `All`, and `LookupData`, thus causing error.

I am not sure why it is selecting an action with `Route` attribute even in case of a regular route. What I should do differently? Or is there any robust way to write a `ActionSelector` for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding empty [Route] to `All` method:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route]
public IEnumerable<TDto> All(){
    ...
}
```